# Injecting HTML produced by PHP

Tags: php, html

This may be a simple question for some of you but i've been investigating it for the last hour and couldn't find the answer. I have a simple login form/script that has the following structure;

```
<?php
PHP code here to check for token (if true) and then check the db for username and password
if the token is false display error message
?>

<HTML>
HTML logon form here that sets the token
</HTML>
```

Now if there is an issue with the logon, i.e the password is incorrect the  php will output the error message, trouble is that it will echo the output at the top of the form. I'd like to be able to insert it at another point of the form. i have a vague idea that i could inject it into the html with something like {logon_error} but i don't know what method thats called or how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the error message in a variable, and use it afterwards.

Here's a working example to help you understand:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['FormSubmit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if ($username === 'admin' && $password === 'hunter2') {
        # success
    } else {
        $error = 'Invalid credentials';
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <div id="errorContainer">
        <?php echo (isset($error)) ? $error : ''; ?>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
        Password: <input type="text" name="password" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="FormSubmit" value="Submit!" />
    </form>
</html>
```

---

If you have multiple checks, and want different error messages to be output, then you could store the error messages in an array instead. Your validation code should look like:

```
if (condition) {
    $error[] = '...'
}
elseif (condition) {
    $error[] = '...'
}
else (condition) {
    $error[] = '...'
}
```

And then, to output it in your HTML, you can use a `foreach` construct with the alternate syntax:

```
<div id="errorContainer">
    <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
        <p class="error-content">
            <?php echo $error; ?>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Note that this is a very basic example and is just for demonstration purposes. **You should *never* trust user input**. Your original form should contain **all the necessary validation** and should not be just a couple of `if` statements.

Comment: i kind of figured it myself (the checking if it was set) although i used the following; <?php if(!empty($error_output)) { echo $error_output;}  ?> which would work the best empty or isset?

Comment: oh and there is already lots of validation including protection against injection

Comment: @Nathan: `empty()` checks if the variable is set **and** if it is it checks it for null, "", 0, etc. `isset()` just checks if is it set - it could be anything that's not `NULL`. So, depends on what you really want to check. But I'd just use `isset()` :)

Comment: @Nathan: I've updated the answer with some more information - it might be helpful for future visitors who are looking for help with the same thing. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can store the error message in a php variable , for e.g. `$error_msg = "Error! ... ";`

And display that wherever you want in the html page like this:

```
<html>
...
   <body>
    ...
    <span><?= $error_msg; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: would i not get an error though if the error variable wasn't set?

Comment: @Nathan: Yes, you would. See my answer for how you can avoid the error (hint: use `isset()`).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store the message in the session or take a look at https://github.com/plasticbrain/PHP-Flash-Messages

the main idea is $error_mesage = 'your error mesage here';

```
loadView('your-view')->with($error_message);
```

It's really simple, if you give more information about what kind of framework you are working with we may be able to assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

**PHP**:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

   if (empty($_POST["username"]))
     {$userErr = "Username is required";}
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<span class="error">* <?php echo $userErr;?></span>
```

You can do whatever you like using `<?php echo ""; ?>` in php to call it on your **html**.